# how to choose k value in k-medoids using elbow method?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

i'm trying this code :
https://gist.github.com/jaganadhg/9a25fb531df47beb13e3

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist, pdist
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()

k = range(1,11)

clusters = [KMeans(n_clusters = c,init = 'k-means++').fit(iris.data) for c in k]
centr_lst = [cc.cluster_centers_ for cc in clusters]

k_distance = [cdist(iris.data, cent, 'euclidean') for cent in centr_lst]
clust_indx = [np.argmin(kd,axis=1) for kd in k_distance]
distances = [np.min(kd,axis=1) for kd in k_distance]
avg_within = [np.sum(dist)/iris.data.shape[0] for dist in distances]

with_in_sum_square = [np.sum(dist ** 2) for dist in distances]
to_sum_square = np.sum(pdist(iris.data) ** 2)/iris.data.shape[0]
bet_sum_square = to_sum_square - with_in_sum_square

kidx = 2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(k, avg_within, 'g*-')
ax.plot(k[kidx], avg_within[kidx], marker='o', markersize=12, \
markeredgewidth=2, markeredgecolor='r', markerfacecolor='None')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('Average within-cluster sum of squares')
plt.title('Elbow for KMeans clustering (IRIS Data)')
```

and have no problem with k-means.
but when i changed k-means to k-medoids

```
clusters = [KMedoids(n_clusters = c).fit(iris.data) for c in k]
```

(i use pyclust k-medoids https://github.com/mirjalil/pyclust/blob/master/pyclust/_kmedoids.py)

i got "None" array

> [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

what's wrong? 
can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `fit` method of that code-you-downloaded-but-don't-understand does not return a value.

Add a `return self` or `return self._clusters` or similar to the `fit` method and it probably behaves as expected, at least for this step.